# Magento API for customer login with session

Tags: php, magento, session

I have searched a lot on Google & StackOverflow but still did not get the code or suggestion for the customer login from another server to create a session.

I used this code but it is not working:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton( 'customer/session' );
Mage::app()->getStore()->setWebsiteId(1);

try {
    $session->login( $email, $password );
    $customer = $session->getCustomer();

    return json_encode(array('status' => 'OK', 'userData' => $this->info($customer->getId())));
}
catch( Exception $e ) {
    return json_encode(array('status' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
}
```

Comment: Which bit isn't working?

Comment: Hi, I used the above code to create session for magento site from another server but its not working

Comment: Yeah, but which bit isn't working? Does it get the session singleton? Does it return an error from the catch? We can't do much with "it doesn't work".

Comment: its responding like this but not creating the session on

Comment: its giving me following result & not creating session on browser for customer

Comment: Mage_Customer_Model_Customer Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => customer
    [_eventObject:protected] => customer
    [_errors:protected] => Array
        (
        )

Comment: [_attributes:protected] => 
    [_addresses:protected] => 
    [_addressesCollection:protected] => 
    [_isDeleteable:protected] => 1
    [_isReadonly:protected] => 
    [_cacheTag:protected] => customer
    [_resourceName:protected] => customer/customer
    [_resource:protected] => 
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => customer/customer_collection
    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
    [_isObjectNew:protected] =>

Comment: [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 2
            [entity_type_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [email] => amail@example.org
            [group_id] => 1
            [increment_id] => 
            [store_id] => 1

Comment: [created_at] => 2017-01-07T03:30:16-08:00
            [updated_at] => 2017-01-07 11:30:16
            [is_active] => 1
            [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
            [created_in] => Default Store View
            [firstname] => Dough
            [lastname] => Deeks
            [password_hash] => aa090101873700a04656c82adca27781:5b9FXuDcId9lDpRIE0roeybU2jJnzgzM
        )

Comment: [_hasDataChanges:protected] => 1
    [_origData:protected] => Array
        (
            [website_id] => 1
            [entity_id] => 2
            [entity_type_id] => 1
            [attribute_set_id] => 0
            [email] => amail@example.org
            [group_id] => 1
            [increment_id] =>

Comment: [store_id] => 1
            [created_at] => 2017-01-07 11:30:16
            [updated_at] => 2017-01-07 11:30:16
            [is_active] => 1
            [disable_auto_group_change] => 0
            [created_in] => Default Store View
            [firstname] => Dough

Comment: [lastname] => Deeks
            [password_hash] => aa090101873700a04656c82adca27781:5b9FXuDcId9lDpRIE0roeybU2jJnzgzM
        )

    [_idFieldName:protected] => entity_id

Comment: [_isDeleted:protected] => 
    [_oldFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [_syncFieldsMap:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)

Comment: Can you please update your original question, instead of posting all that as comments.

Comment: Improve sentence structure

Comment: got the solution from another resource. thanks thebluefox

Comment: Any solution please?